# Function date_trunc does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq

I have a C# query using linq with two datetime fields Im trying to compare. The datetime field in the Postgres DB is stored as timestamp with time zone. However for some reason I am receiving "function date_trunc(unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist" error although in the debug view it shows I am passing the correct parameters. Please note: MyDate field is Nullable

C#

```
  _context.MyDbObject.Where(a => DateTime.UtcNow.Date >= a.MyDate.Value.Date).AsQueryable();
```

Query shown in Debug View

```
(date_trunc('day', now(), 'UTC') >= date_trunc('day', a."MyDate", 'UTC')))
```

Error

```
MessageText: function date_trunc(unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: usually its good to see the actual sql generated; in dbcontext class you can attach log method  eg. 'Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;' and see why your date is not valid; does it carry time zone component?

Comment: @Rafal yes it carries timezone but I use the Date field to strip that off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not direct answer to your question, but if you care about database indexes, do not use date truncation in queries. Your query can be rewritten.

```cs
var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var endDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);

var query = _context.MyDbObject
    .Where(a => a.MyDate.Value < endDate)
    .AsQueryable();

// or records for current day

var query = _context.MyDbObject
    .Where(a => a.MyDate.Value >= currentDate && a.MyDate.Value < endDate)
    .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thank you this actually helped me alot, by not using the date truncation in the where clause I was able to avoid that postgres function but also increase the efficiency for indexes.